# How to Test a Deployment in Octopus Deploy

Tags: testing, integration-testing, octopus-deploy

I am working on automating our ASP.Net projects' release, using Octopus Deploy. While creating release in Octopus, I am performing following testing completely manually:

I am checking if release is deploying

1. Everything expected
2. In the expected places
3. All required services or web services were restarted
4. All Pre/Post deploy scripts ran successfully

This means going to different servers and reading release log generated by Octopus Deploy. It leaves risk of introducing mistakes and any future change can make deployment unstable.

Is there any tool to perform a kind of integration testing for Octopus Deploy Release or automate the process mentioned above. I am also open to writing a quick tool automating my testing but then I was wondering what will be the best way to go about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just read the logs on the Octopus release details page? It provides a direct capture of all output generated while the deployment was running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Octopus 2.0 we're building a [powerful API that gives you access to everything in Octopus](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/wiki). Using the API you'll be able to create and deploy a release, as well as read the activity logs and see what was deployed. You could hook this up to an automated test (which is what we're doing internally for end-to-end automated testing).